# How to find the maximum value that is obtained in the sum of n numbers in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a list of numbers, of which any `n` number of numbers can be taken and summed up.

For example:

In the image below is an example senario, where the choice of answering 'n' questions is given and the max of the sum of the combination of the marks has to be obtained out of the maximum marks.

[image]

I need to find the maximum value obtained.

With reference to the above image, we get the maximum of the sum of any 4 numbers in Q1 and maximum of the sum of any 3 numbers in Q2

[image]

Comment: You need to explain better, do you want the total of 1A, 1B, 1C etc? What is the example outcome actually counting?

Comment: This doesn't show any attempt or effort, which is regarded as a prerequisite here. Would you give this a go, Anul, and then show us where you are stuck specifically?

Comment: @halfer: The area of issue for me was to have the maximum total no matter how we order the question number... hope you understand..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply by using the formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(B7:G7,{1,2,3,4}))
```

A Simple set up of your sheet with Formulas will look like this

[image]

But you do have to define the ranges once for each question, After that a simple drag will fill in the values for all students.

Comment: Thanks a lot... could you let me know if we can add a conditional check to determine the elements of the array...